# can't access this.table property in javascript class

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, oop

I create a class in js which create a MySQL model like this :

```
class Model {
  constructor(options = {}, table) {
    this.options = options;
    this.table = table;
    this.create();
  }
  create() {
    let queryString = `INSERT INTO ${this.table}`;
    let fieldsString = ``;
    let valuesString = ``;
    for (let prop in this.options) {
      fieldsString += `${prop},`;
      valuesString += `${this.options[prop]},`;
      //console.log(prop, this.options[prop]);
    }
    fieldsString = fieldsString.slice(0, -1);
    valuesString = valuesString.slice(0, -1);
    queryString = `${queryString} (${fieldsString}) VALUES (${valuesString})`;
    console.log(queryString);
  }
}

class UsersModel extends Model {
  constructor(options = {}, table) {
    super(options, table);
    this.table = "users";
  }
}
const u1 = new UsersModel({
  username: "test",
  mail: "darya",
});
```

when I run the constructor variable `queryString` looks like this: `INSERT INTO undefined (username, mail) VALUES (test, Darya)` why `this.table` is undefined? what I missed?
I will appreciate any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you first call is create (in super) and only after you set this.table.

```js
class Model {
  constructor(table) {
    // table is undefined, call create..
    this.table = table;
    this.create();
  }
  create() {
    let queryString = `INSERT INTO ${this.table}`;
    console.log(queryString);
  }
}

class UsersModel extends Model {
  constructor(table) {
    // table is undefined, call super..
    super(table); 
    this.table = "users";
    // here you already have table name, so create works with it
    this.create(); 
  }
}

new UsersModel();
```

Comment: I understood what I missed! Thx for your help!

Answer (score -1):

I would remove the table parameter from the UsersModel constructor, because you aren't passing it in. It also shouldn't change, a table name will usually not be dynamic. Here's what I would change it to:

```
class UsersModel extends Model {
  constructor(options) {
    super(options, "users")
  }
}
```

I also chose not to make the options parameter optional (pun not intended). I would even recommend taking the username and mail as separate parameters, then passing them down as an object to the base Model constructor.